# Function that returns different types depending on some value

Tags: typescript

I have a function fetchFruitById that takes an id and looks up a fruit in the database (I am using the example method "someMethodThatReturnsFruit" as a stand in for the DB call. The database can return objects of different shapes (notice that the properties has different shapes).

I want my function (fetchFruitById) to return a typed object - either Apple or Orange.

```js
// I do not control this function. It is just an example of a function that returns different shapes.
function someMethodThatReturnsFruit(id: string) {
  if (id === '1') {
    return {
      id: '1',
      type: 'Apple',
      properties: {
        color: 'red',
        isCrispy: true
      }
    };
  } else {
    return {
      id: '2',
      type: 'Orange',
      properties: {
        color: 'orange',
        isSoft: true
      }
    };
  }
}

// I do control this function.
async function fetchFruitById(id: string) {
  const couldBeAppleOrOrange = await someMethodThatReturnsFruit(id);
  return couldBeAppleOrOrange;
}

const fruit1 = await fetchFruitById('1');
// This should be type Apple.

const fruit2 = await fetchFruitById('2');
// This should be type Orange.
```

I think I could simply have a bunch of conditional code in the fetchFruitById to return the type, something like...

```
if (couldBeAppleOrOrange.type === 'Apple') return couldBeAppleOrOrange as Apple;
// etc...
```

But that does not seem like a good approach, especially, if I want to add support for more fruit types.

I feel like there must be a solution involving generics, but I cannot figure out where to start. The fruit example is obviously obviously just for demonstration. The main thing is that my types all have different shapes in the "properties" field.

Comment: That conditional code doesn't actually have the effect you want; the function would return `Apple | Orange` for every call.  You can use generics, but you'll have to use type assertions or the like no matter what, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mZBOom). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz while it's a bit verbose, I believe overloads provide better readability provided you only have a few cases to cover.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your suggestion. The main issue with that approach is that in reality, the fruits (in this simple example) are in a database, and there could be millions, each with a unique id. We will not have the map of ids to types.

Comment: It's been a month since you posted this, and it's completely paged out of my mind. I'm not sure it's worth re-engaging. Is there any expected time-frame for your response if I do come up with another approach? Or should I just disengage?

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, I have moved on with a different solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could use is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types), based on the `type` property:

```
type FruitType = 'Apple' | 'Orange'

interface Fruit {
    id: number,
    type: FruitType,
    properties: {
        color: string,
        isCrispy: boolean,
    }
}


interface Apple extends Fruit {
    type: 'Apple';
}

interface Orange extends Fruit {
    type: 'Orange';
}


declare function someMethodThatReturnsFruit(id: string): Apple | Orange;

async function fetchFruitById(id: string) {
    const couldBeAppleOrOrange = await someMethodThatReturnsFruit(id);
    return couldBeAppleOrOrange;
}

const fruit1 = await fetchFruitById('1');

if (fruit1.type === 'Apple') {
    type Test = typeof fruit1; // Apple
}
else {
    type Test = typeof fruit1; // Orange
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbACrmgXigcgIJhgA2EOUAPrgPJwCGAdgOakBQLS9wEcAZrQMbR4yYFADeLKFKhIAJgC4o9BAFsARtwA0k6aEiLhKdJG3SoYOAHtIcYEggBnRRLNn+lopbiKHwOB0ZTVykkBwBhfwcwEEU1Sw8IBiCpAF8WNLYOLl4BaAJiaAgADy56WQdYRBRxHSk9CEV8QhIcAG50zM5uPkEoGgZmKGLS8sqRGrN6xv6mUnaMllkIfiJaOGgeBHp+O0t6KAdLFQgAWQhgAAtLWVQL2mAAJXOEOHoHQ2AACjkfPwCASkU+RIFD6dFm7RYtAcIG2UE2212+x4534Fw+ACEQABJWTfBQHP5Mf4TaTuN6idwIIiyDEQYEQGgzQbYWgAd1o1UOxzOl2ut3uT2ALzeH3x-3aZnWwteUCpNLpDKZ4OY8zY5N88KqwAAjFBWRzqijgGjMTi8TgdTgJZkeFBPjxtTqAHT1fWYbBNArW0l1DBQVCOUTYeqWO2OkQ61pQAD0MagDI6ECIDmgLl0-sDmpDGDDWsj0bjYIGEHSQA)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'll still need to check the type and/or typecast as needed, but you can specify the return types of the method:

```
function someMethodThatReturnsFruit(id: string): Apple|Orange {
...
}
```

If you have a 'parent' type like `Fruit` that each fruit implements that will make it easier to add more types later.